# Oracle SQL Collection Array Parsing

Tags: java, php, sql, arrays, oracle

I have a PHP script that is running a query that returns an Oracle Java Array / Collection. Example of the results are below:

```
oracle.sql.ARRAY@134d8c8
```

How do I read the values of that array / collection using PHP ?

Comment: I do not think that the values of the array can be retrieved as is. That is probably the equivalent of doing `array.toString()`. Who ever is sending you the array most likely needs to serialize it.